# Add a RDP Remmina host by command line

Tags: networking, server, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc

I am using remmina to connect to remote machines using the RDP protocol.

What I am looking for is to be able to connect to remote machines without having to open the graphical environment.

The way I have found is, first of all, run remmina from the graphical interface and create a host profile, make the first connection via GUI and once I have made the first connection by GUI remmina creates a configuration file in `~ user / .local / share / remmina / hostconffile.remmina` that's when I can run a `remmina -c [path / hostconf.remmina]` and connect without opening the GUI.

I would like to know how I can create a host profile and be able to connect through the RDP protocol without having to do the above.

If any clarification is necessary, I am attentive to the comments
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Since the profiles created by `remmina` are text files, you can create your own and put under the same directory, by using the already created ones as "examples".

Comment: Yep, already thinked about that, the problem it's that im using Zabbix and I'm doing a really hard script